# Altium schematic component wires connection on component move

Tags: altium

I'm trying to move a component with its wires, but after moving, wires connect to each other or to components other pins.

before component move:
[image]

after component move:
[image]

Comment: Try to select the wires with the component, then move all of them together

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that your component was created on a different grid than your schematic, so when you move the part the wires snap to the new schematic grid and/or nearest electrical hotspot (i.e. a pin). I strongly recommend against creating schematic symbols with a grid other than what your schematic uses. Your best bet would be to go in and edit the part symbol in the library to update the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, Altium (and probably most schematic CAD programs) had two commands to move components.

The MOVE component would just move the component, leaving the wires alone for you to fix.

The DRAG command would move both the component and connected tracks, which would generally result in the mess you show.  The programs are not smart enough to workout how to move wire segments to maintain the desired connections.

A solution is to delete the connected wire segments, move the component, then re-draw the disconnected wires.